# Is there a good guide out there for setting MapServer up on an existing windows apache server?

Tags: mapserver

I have been interested in trying out MapServer and have no problem setting up a windows development box.  Seems like all the MapServer implementations on Windows include Apache, PHP, MapServer, and a variety of other software.

Unfortunately, if I wanted to use Mapserver in my production environment, I do not want to uninstall my functioning and stable Apache to replace it with the packaged MapServer download.  I understand that I can take pieces out of the package and use them with my existing Apache but I would really like to have a clear set of instructions rather than references from 4 different websites.

I am looking for clear instructions/how-to in 1 place.

Comment: What is it that you want to set up? Do you want instructions on just configuring Mapserver with IIS, or PHP and Chameleon as well? Mapserver is a challenge because its a mishmash of semi-overlapping technologies, making documenting installation a little more tricky.

Comment: I am interested in configuration for IIS and apache.  My problem, I guess, is that I am not sure what I need because the software is a mishmash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found this, is it of any use?

http://onegeology.org/wmsCookbook/4_2_4.html

James

Comment: I got to looking at it and I think it will help

Answer (score 1):

There is the document "One Scotland: One Geography: One Information Network: Creating Scotland's Spatial Data Infrastructure: Cookbook 1 - How to serve a Scottish SDI and INSPIRE conformant Web Map Service" at http://www.scotland.gov.uk/Publications/2010/05/06161701/0

For your exact case e.g "make Mapserver works on an existing Apache", see http://www.scotland.gov.uk/Publications/2010/05/06161701/10

Comment: This is based on the OneGeology Cookbook

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may also help, its taken from the GVS, an open source web mapping solution from UNBC to help First Nationss collect information and respond to resource development within their respective area of interest.

http://datashare.gis.unbc.ca/gvs/documentation.php

http://datashare.gis.unbc.ca/gvs/Utilizing-the-GVS-feb07.pdf

EDIT: In the PDF link, there is a matrix which show how they have incorporated UMN Mapserver into their Apache configuration and going further into the documentation, how to set up the scripts to handle this exchange of information.